How to make input using checkbox with codeigniter 4.5.5
I want to make a form using checkbox in CI 4.5.5, but I got an error
"Array to string conversion"
Form file
<form action="" id="form_validation" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="xxx">Diteruskan kepada</label>
                       
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="terusan[]" value="1">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Checkbox</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="terusan[]" value="2">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Checkbox</label>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="basic_checkbox">Dengan hormat harap</label>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="tindakan[]" value="1">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Checkbox</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="tindakan[]"  value="2">
                            <label class="form-check-label">Checkbox</label>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

Controller File
       $array_te = $this->request->getPost('terusan');
       $terusan['terusan'] = implode(',',$array_te);
       $array_ti = $this->request->getPost('tindakan');
       $tindakan['tindakan'] = implode(',',$array_ti);
       $data = [
        'terusan' => $this->$terusan,
        'tindakan' => $this->$tindakan,
       ];
       $surat->tambah($data);

Model file for insert the form
public function tambah($data)
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table('tb_surat_masuk');
        $builder->insert($data);
    }

I got an Error
"Array to string conversion"
APPPATH\Controllers\SuratController.php at line 50
           'no_surat' => $this->request->getPost('no_surat'),
44         'tgl_terima' => $this->request->getPost('tgl_terima'),
45         'no_agenda' => $this->request->getPost('no_agenda'),
46         'sifat' => $this->request->getPost('sifat'),
47         'kat1' => $this->request->getPost('id_kat1'),
48         'kat2' => $this->request->getPost('id_kat2'),
49         'perihal' => $this->request->getPost('perihal'),
50         **'terusan' => $this->$terusan,** --> The error in this line
51         'tindakan' => $this->$tindakan,
52         'catatan'=> $this->request->getPost( 'catatan'),
53         'file' => $fileName,
54        ];
55        $surat->tambah($data);


What should I do?

Are you sure you should be using $this->$terusan ? Is $terusan a property in the object? From the looks of it 'terusan' => $this->$terusan, should equal 'terusan' => $terusan, but hard to know.

No problem! All part of the fun ...!
